# Alamofire encoding invalidURL

Tags: swift, get, alamofire

Good afternoon all, newbie here trying to learn Swift / Alamofire. I've struggled with this for almost two days and am ready to move on.

My URL appears to be created corrected, but I get an error when making the  request.  In looking at the Xcode debug logs, it looks like my single quotes are being escaped when the request is being sent.

```
let owner : String = "me@corp.local"

func getDeploymentsByOwner(token: String, owner: String, success: @escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {

    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)",
        ]
    print(owner)


    let url = "https://corp.local?$filter=owners/ref eq '\(owner)'"


    // created URL is https://corp.local?$filter=owners/ref eq 'me@corp.local'


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJSON = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            success(resJSON)
        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error = responseObject.result.error
            print(error)
            failure(error!)
        }
    }
```

My error message looks like this
// Xocde debug error

```
Optional(Alamofire.AFError.invalidURL("https//:corp.local?$filter=owners/ref eq \'me@corp.local\'"))
invalidURL(https://corp.local?$filter=owners/ref eq \'me@corp.local\'")
```

I Can get all the items without $filter, so the request works as long as the filter is omitted.

// Postman works with the generated URL, but the one with the backslashes () won't

Comment: try to encode url

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  How do you encode it?

Comment: where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 14):

Thank you for your response, unfortunately it did not work.  The entire URL got mangled including the hostname.  But it did give me a starting point to figure it out, thank you.  The working code is below

```
    let url = "https://corp.local?$filter=owners/ref eq '\(owner)'"
    let encodedUrl = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
let url = "https//:corp.local?$filter=owners/ref eq \'me@corp.local\'"
let urlEncoded = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
print(urlEncoded!)
```